# Indices similar to EVI for vegetation health analysis using UAV multispectral data

Tags: raster, remote-sensing, vegetation-index

I know NDVI is the most commonly used index to start with vegetation health analysis. I am looking for other indices that can be calculated when the available UAV imagery has `NIR`, `Red`, `Red Edge`, `Blue` and `Green` bands. I found `EVI`, but since I  don't have satellite data, so that's out of the question as the C1 and C2 coefficients don't apply here. I can't even find MSI as I don't have the SWIR band. Similarly, I can't find CCI, because I don't have the TIR band. What other indices can I calculate using the bands I have, when the purpose is to assess whether the vegetation is stressed or not and how the photosynthetic activity is in a arid desert environment?

```
EVI = 2.5 * ((NIR – Red) / ((NIR) + (C1 * Red) – (C2 * Blue) + L))
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://www.indexdatabase.de/ ? It's a fantastic resource for this kind of work.

Comment: @om_henners, the camera is called RedEdge-M_5_5 (five band multispectral sensor), and it's not in the list of sensors on that website. Can you please tell me which sensor in that list will be similar to this sensor?

Comment: Afraid not off the top of my head. The sensor itself should have details about the wavelength and the bandwidth, and you should be able to compare that to the bands listed for each of the sensors (there's a list you can go through here: https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/bs.php ). That said I think a lot of it will be up to your judgement as fit for purpose. Note most of the forumulas ([CCI](https://www.indexdatabase.de/db/i-single.php?id=224) for instance) include bandwidths required, so maybe start with the required calculations?

Comment: Remove the R tag because its not an R question (at least not until you find something you want to calculate) and added "remote sensing" tag.